# Pandas : Raise error when a line is incomplete

Tags: python, pandas, csv

pandas refuses to read files that have too many commas (after the first line) :

Trying to read_csv the following :

```
col1,col2,col3
foo,1,2
bar,2,3
zob,0,3,4
```

Will give me an error

However, pandas accepts the following no matter the options I tried in read_csv :

```
col1,col2,col3
foo,1,2
bar,2,3
zob,0
```

And will just consider that the value in col3 for the last line is null

**Is there any pandas way to raise an exception when this (too few fields in one row) happens ?** (In my case, it means the source of the file is faulty and the file needs to be downloaded again).

It seems error_bad_lines only concern lines with too many commas.

I can count separately the number of commas for each line before using read_csv, but I'd like to know if an option within pandas exists because it seems more natural / to ease code readability.

Comment: what you expect to see for your example

Comment: @Wen :  Any exception that I can raise to tell my program that he needs to start over the download. The same behaviour as happens in the first example (read_csv errs because too many commas) would be great.

Comment: Can your file contain NaN values?

Comment: If you are just checking for an incomplete download, you could first count the number of fields in the last row only - before parsing as csv. But even with a correct last row the download could be incomplete.

Comment: @MaxU no the file does not contain any NaN values, so indeed this could be a lead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

> he file does not contain any NaN values

```
In [85]: pd.read_csv(fn)
Out[85]:
  col1  col2  col3
0  foo     1   2.1
1  bar     2   3.1
2  zob     0   NaN
```

so you can raise an exception if the following condition is met:

```
In [86]: pd.read_csv(fn).isnull().any().any()
Out[86]: True
```

---

**Old answer:**

Possible solution:

consider the following input CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3
foo,1,2.1
bar,2,3.1
zob,0
```

the following works:

```
In [50]: pd.read_csv(fn, dtype={'col3':'float'})
Out[50]:
  col1  col2  col3
0  foo     1   2.1
1  bar     2   3.1
2  zob     0   NaN
```

but if we instruct Pandas not to treat empty string as `NaN`'s, then it'll throw an exception:

```
In [51]: pd.read_csv(fn, na_values=['NAN','NaN','#NA'], keep_default_na=False, dtype={'col3':'float'})
...
skipped
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: That doesn't work if ",," is considered a valid row, but "a,1" is not.  Or rather, if null values are permissible, but they must be explicitly specified.